# How to draw path with multiple curves in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-design

[image]
[image]
I am trying to draw path with multiple curves as shown in picture 1
But the curve getting drawn has breaks in between as shown in second picture
Below is the code I am using

```
 Path drawPath(Constant c) {
   
    Path path = Path();
    //width,height
    path.moveTo(c.width! / 2, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(c.width! / 4, c.height! * 0.10, c.width! / 4 + 100,
        c.height! * 0.10 + 100);
    path.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(c.width! / 4 + 100 + 50,
        c.height! * 0.10 + 100, c.width! - 300, c.height! / 4 * 2);
    return path;
  }
```

How can I make the curve joint smooth? What will be the right approach?